# launching threads via submit button

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets

Part of my app is to provide an interface to an operator to manage multiple printers of smart cards. 
A JSP page displays all printers and each printer has a print button. 
I want the operator to press several buttons and each button pressed starts a thread. 
Threads should run in parallel and pressing a button does not cancel the processing of the previous button. 
Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem and thank you in advance.

Comment: What would the Thread do? What have you tried so far? Ideally, post some code, because that's what SO can help you with best.

Comment: each thread extract data from a synchronised queue and pass it to printer. I prepared thread but do not know haw to lauch them after each button press

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got the core of your question, but as far as I understood it you get a request of some kind and want to start a new thread for it. That does not seem to be related to JSP and could be encapsulated in a method like

```
private void startPrinterThread(final String printerIdentifier) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //some code depending on printerIdentifier
            //which will run in parallel
        }
    }.start();
}
```

And, of course some typical multi-threading related questions arise from that, like

- Can multiple threads for the *same* printer be started?
- Does the operator need to be *informed* that a thread for a printer is running or finished?
- Should it be possible to *abort* a running thread?

In either case you have to keep track of the running threads, meaning putting the created `Thread` object into a collection like a `Map<String, Thread>` where you use the printer's identifier as key.

Comment: thank you for answering. the method startPrintingThread where should i put it to be launched when i press button beacause i have read that launching threads in servlet isn't recommanded

Comment: However, as Philipp pointed out, you probably should give some more details what specific problem you are facing. And if deriving from `Thread` and using `Thread.start()` already was the whole story, you might consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: the problem is not in thread but in how to launch thread from JSP.
For example the operator press button"print" coresponding to the first printer, so a thread is launched and while that thread is running he press button "print" of printer 2 . as a result i should have two threads: one for printer1 and the other for printer 2

Comment: The code above does exactly that. Each time the method is invoked, a _new_ instance of `Thread` is created and it's task (the content of method `run()`) is executed parallel to and independet from previous created threads. It even allows the creation of multiple threads for the _same_ printer, which is why you should keep track of the threads already running. But, most importantly: Each request, caused by clicking of a button, will go the same way until you create the thread. The request then returns, giving the user the ability to click another button, while the created thread keeps running.